# How to write this rule using mod rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains, like example.org, example.com or example.net

So i want to write a rule using mod rewrite that catches the URL and send the user from
http://www.example.org/random-page or http://www.example.net/random-page to http://www.example.com/random-page

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example\.(org|net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: It don't have to be necessary /vids, i want to send all the trafic from other domains (.org, .net, .es) to .com. Thanks!

Comment: Alright edited now. It will not redirect every URI. Make sure this rule in the `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess file` of `example.org/net`